# Runtime Error 450; Why i cannot debug it?

Tags: vba, excel

Why whenever I record a macro and want to set a variable -- dialogue box will automatically say that wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. Can anybody help me? Because I am still new using VBA.

```
Sub Advanced_Filter()
'
' Advanced_Filter Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'
    Set DataSH = Sheet1
        DataSH.Range("B8").CurrentRegion.Range.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range( _
        "L8:L9"), CopyToRange:=Range("N8:T8"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Range("L8:L9") and Range("N8:T8") only 'belong' to Sheet1 if Sheet1 is the active sheet. You need to provide proper parent worksheet references to all of the range/cells references.

To ease multiple assignments, a With ... End With block may help. Note that within the block, Range is referred to as .Range. This passes the parent worksheet reference.

```
option explicit

Sub Advanced_Filter()
'
' Advanced_Filter Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
'

    dim DataSH as worksheet
    Set DataSH = Sheet1

    with DataSH 
        .Range("B8").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                     CriteriaRange:=.Range("L8:L9"), CopyToRange:=.Range("N8:T8"), _
                     Unique:=False
    end with

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I try to copy your coding to my modules. But, unfortunately, it cannot debug because it will appear expected: end of statement and highlight at action.